# How can I add a custom code formatter to VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, editor

I have a formatter with the signature `def align_assignment_expressions(code: str) -> str:`  which takes some python code as a string and returns a formatted version. How can I use this as a formatter in VSCode? Specifically when I use the format chord (shift+alt+f on windows, ctrl+shift+I on linux) I want this formatter to be run on the current file.

PS: I'm aware that Black etc. exist - I want to use my own.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Bonus: If you can tell me a way to *first* run black and then my script that'd be perfect.

Comment: related docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices

Comment: if existing VSC Extensions don't provide you the subject functionality nor allow to specify custom rules, you can request it at their repositories/{feedback channels}, otherwise you need to make your own Extension .